# Using Two Datagridview but Problem Displaying Only One

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview, vb.net-2010

Hi i have a problem im using two datagrid view but only one is displaying 
If not one the same data on different datagridview. But i have two different queries on my codes.

This example of two dummy db.

```
subject table
----------------------------------------------
|subject_name| subject_code | subject_units|
----------------------------------------------
|MATH        | MATH101      |      3       |
|English     | ENG101       |      2       |
|CALCULUS    | MATH300      |      3       |


student_subject table
-----------------------------------------------
|student_id  |  sub_id     |   grade       |
-----------------------------------------------
| 1235       |     5       |      3         |
| 1235       |     3       |      4         |
| 1236       |     7       |      4         |
```

That is the data i want to fill on my two datagridview but it is not working properly 
**UPDATE:** I Tried but Only Display the table on student_subject
Here is my code:

```
    myconn = New MySqlConnection
        myconn.ConnectionString = connstring
        myconn.Open()

        ds = New DataSet
        tables = ds.Tables

// DISPLAY DATAGRIDVIEW2
     da = New MySqlDataAdapter("Select student_id,sub_id,grade FROM student_subject", myconn)
        da.Fill(ds, "student_subject")
        DataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        DataGridView2.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells)

//DISPLAY DATAGRIDVIEW1
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter("Select subject_id as 'ID',subject_name as 'SUBJECT',subject_code as 'SUBJECT CODE',subject_units as 'UNITS',sem as 'Semester',year_level as 'YEAR LEVEL' from subject_bsit", myconn)
        da.Fill(ds, "student_subject")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells)
```

Answer (score 0):

All what you have to do is adding this binding line code as below:

```
    DataGridView2.DataSource = DS.Tables(0)
```

"You just miss it"

Very easy, Hope this works ^_^

Comment: Same Error it will only display the student_subject table on both datagridview. 
Datagridview1 and 2 . The second query not working thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem by adding new dataset and new data adapater
And use it for the other datagridview.

```
Public ds2 As System.Data.DataSet
Private tables2 As System.Data.DataTableCollection
Public da2 As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter
```